# Is a Monopoly equilibrium also a Nash equilibrium?

Tags: nash-equilibrium, monopoly

Consider a monopoly with price power in the market and the demand is a function of price. Can the result of such a monopoly problem be called a nash equilibrium?

Answer (score 4):

In a somewhat degenerate way, yes. The specified demand function is a trivial case of a best response function describing the optimal quantity demanded for any given price of the monopolist. The monopolist's optimal profit-maximizing price in turn is the best response facing this demand. So you end up with a Nash equilibrium, where each player plays his/her best response and the choices are mutually consistent. Put differently, no player has any incentive to deviate.

Comment: Relatedly, one can have also a competitive market where the monopolist price is a Nash equilibrium. See the Diamond paradox from industrial organization, where there are nonnegligible search costs to finding the best price.

Comment: Why is this »degenerate« ... whatever that means in an economic context?

Comment: Because I would not consider this your typical case of the intersection of two fully-fledged best response functions.